# No Such Directory

Tags: magento2

Magento 2, version 3.2.x was working fine, but after upgrading to version 2.3.3 it started giving error 500. I have tried running permissions for folders and files, compile, re-index, flush cache... but is still not working. When I check exeptions.log file on hosting I found the error below. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"} []
```

Comment: by which method you updated ?

Comment: Hi @Pawan. I updated via SSH. But it seems also that the cPanel built-in application manager "Installatron" also automattically updated it. But usually with that incident it works just fine.